# Manipulation of orthogonal vectors under a rotation in 3D space

Tags: matrices, vectors

A course I'm doing has the following result quoted for two orthogonal vectors, $v$ and $w$ under a rotation in 3D space
$v · w = Av · Aw$

= $(Av)^T*(Aw)$

= $v^T*(A^T*A)w$

= $v · (A^T*Aw)$

Now I can follow that until the last line since I believe $(AB)^T=B^T*A^T$, I don't understand the relation between the two last lines, how does $v^T$... become $v$ · ...?

Comment: What is "T"? I do not know what is "T"

Comment: What is $A$? The rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Just expand quantities $v^Tw$ and $v\cdot w$ by coordinates and you'll see that $v^Tw=v\cdot w$.

Comment: Yeah I realise now my problem is just not understanding vectors in general. and what the products between them actually mean.

Thanks